# P value and critical value in hypothesis testing

Tags: python, statistics, scipy.stats

I need little clarification in p value and critical value approach in hypothesis testing regarding below example.

```
Null Hypothesis : population mean = 80

Alternative : population mean != 80

sample_mean = 78

sample_std = 2.5 n = 40
```

after calculating Z statistic that gives value of -5.063, which falls in rejection region (with 95% confidence level) thus **rejects null**. But if I calculate p_value from test statistic using `scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(-5.063))` in python it **accepts null**. So whats happening here. I need guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> So whats happening here.

The premise:

> But if I calculate p_value from test statistic using `scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(-5.063))` in python it **accepts null**.

is in error. `scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(-5.063))` returns `2.0635492667766891e-07`. This is a small p-value, so the probability of observing such an extreme statistic value under the null hypothesis is small. For most common significance thresholds (including 0.05, which corresponds with the 95% confidence you specified), this would be taken as evidence against the null hypothesis.

(Technical note: since your alternative is two-sided and the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis is symmetric about the origin, your p-value should be twice this. It would still be quite small.)

For more information about how hypothesis tests work, please see the SciPy tutorial [Resampling and Monte Carlo Methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/resampling.html). Although its aim is to introduce users to SciPy's resampling and Monte Carlo functionality, it also attempts to present the fundamentals of null hypothesis significance testing in an intuitive way.

---

All that said, it sounds like you should be using a t-test since you do not know the population standard deviation. Consider using [`scipy.stats.ttest_1samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html).